# Девиз наш — «Все за одного!»

Tags: грамматика

Как правильно?

`Девиз наш — «Все за одного!»`

`Девиз наш — все за одного`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Название девиза **обязательно** в кавычках. Плюс в конце предложения нужна точка, несмотря на восклицательный знак.

`Девиз наш — «Все за одного!».`

**[«Грамота.ру»](http://classic2.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=215551)**:

> Нужна ли точка после кавычек в предложении: Ее жизненный девиз – «Вперед, к цели!».
>
> ---
>
> **Ответ справочной службы русского языка**
>
> ---
>
> Да, точка нужна.

Точка нужна, потому что в кавычках не прямая речь, а это правило распространяется только на неë.

Answer (score 1):

```
 Нас четверо, ещё пока мы вместе!
 Но дело есть
 И это дело чести!
 Девиз наш "Все за одного"
 Лишь в этом наш успех!
 
 Д'Артаньян и три мушкетера. Текст песни
```

Все зависит **от ситуации:**

(1) **Цитирование** известной песни (прямая речь, точка не нужна):

Они любили повторять клятву мушкетеров: **Девиз наш — «Все за одного!»**

(2) **Косвенная речь** (нужна точка):

*Надо помнить, что "**Девиз наш — «Все за одного!**".*

(3) Использование фразы **без цитирования:**

*Девиз наш — **все за одного**, вот что надо помнить.*

*Девиз наш — **"все за одного"**, закон у нас такой.*

**Примеры из Нацкорпуса**

Кого помню, все были честные, все прямые, **все за одного и каждый за всех.** Анатолий Найман. Любовный интерес (1998-1999)

Словом, «**один за всех, все за одного»** — главный девиз дореволюционных скаутов и наших советских мушкетеров.Виктор Некрасов. Маленькая печальная повесть (1986)